# How to export a 3d model's hairs as gltf or fbx

Tags: particles, hair, .fbx, gltf

I have made a 3d model's hair using hair particles system. First I selected the faces of my model where I need to place the hair such as the skull , eyebrows and beard and then I added hair curves by selecting shift+A and selecting hair from the menu. After this I created the hair using the different brushes.
Now the problem is when I m trying to export this model as gltf or fbx the hair is not getting exported, the model is bald and without eyebrows! FYI I have assigned a custom material to the hair consisting of a color ramp to get the appropriate color of the hair. I tried converting the hair curves to mesh but then I m losing the color of the hair and it turns black completely and even if I change the material assigned to the hair it still remains black in colour.
Can someone please tell what is wrong or is it not possible to export this hair from blender.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Sorry, no built-in solution for hair in glTF currently.  Maybe someday in the future...